# How to make time ago from json in flutter

Tags: flutter

Is it possible if I have json with the timestamp like this

```
{
"modified": "2018-11-14T16:25:21",
}
```

and I want to make time ago in flutter. eg.5 minutes ago

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages?q=ago

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/simple_moment

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:simple_moment/simple_moment.dart';

main() {
  var datetoCompare = new Duration(seconds: 21,minute : 25, hour:16); //And so with month, year and Day.
  var dateForComparison = new DateTime.now().add(datetoCompare);
  var moment = new Moment.now();
  print(moment.from(dateForComparison));
}
```

This Package helps in showing relative time in flutter.

Simple Moment package -

> https://pub.dev/packages/simple_moment#-readme-tab-

Answer (score 0):

For Seconds:

```
yourDate.difference(DateTime.now()).inSeconds;
```

For Minutes:

```
yourDate.difference(DateTime.now()).inMinutes;
```

For Hours:

```
yourDate.difference(DateTime.now()).inHours;
```